# Typescript - How to solve " Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'XXXX' "?

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined

I have interface defined with some properties. When trying to access the service I am getting this error - Type 'undefined' is not assignable in displayfile at `this.isOpen`. I need help to resolve this error.

Note - I can not set values in config file such as `"strictNullChecks":false`

Interface

```
export interface DataFile {
  file?: DataFile[];
  location: string;
}
```

Typescript class

```
  isOpen?: DataFile;

  Scan(aero: string, TeamClass: string) {
    if (TeamClass === 'Hawkins') {
      if (this.redService.name.file && this.redService.name.file.length > 0) {
        this.isOpen = this.redService.name.file.filter((data: DataFile) => data.location == aero[0])[0];
      }
    }
    
    this.displayfile(this.isOpen).then(async () => {  ----->>>>>> Error at this.isOpen
            //rest of the functionality
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I am getting error-

```
 Argument of type 'DataFile | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type
'DataFile'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'DataFile'.
```

Comment: The real question here is what do you want to do if `this.isOpen` is `undefined`? Right now, you're passing it to `this.displayfile`, but `this.displayfile` doesn't allow for an `undefined` argument.

Comment: Alternatively, if `this.isOpen` is _never_ undefined, then you need to fix it's typing to `isOpen: DataFile;`

Comment: If I set `isOpen: DataFile;` then I am getting this error `Property 'isOpen' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting `isOpen` with a question mark it picks up two types: one that's `DataFile` (your type) and `undefined`. That's the main reason why Typescript is reporting an error.

To resolve it you have two options:

- Check if `isOpen` populates with data, i.e.:

```js
if (!isOpen) { /* do something */ }
...rest of code
```

- Prepend `isOpen` with a `!` (i.e., `this.isOpen!`) that way you force the type to not be undefined. Not recommended because if it is indeed undefined you'll run into errors inside your `this.displayfile` function.

Reference on the question mark operator here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-use-question-mark-in-typescript-variable/

Comment: You mean something like `if (!isOpen) {this.displayfile(this.isOpen).then(async () => {  -
            //rest of the functionality}}}); }`, wrap `!isOpen`condition around displayfile?

Comment: More like, `if (!isOpen) // don't continue with the functionality.` The exclamation point's context here is a NOT operator.

Comment: Okay so in my case I want `if (isOpen) {this.displayfile(this.isOpen).then(async () => {  -             //rest of the functionality}}}); }` Right?

Comment: That's another way, yes. The pattern I'm recommending is more a *guard clause*, meaning we check if it "exists" first. https://learningactors.com/javascript-guard-clauses-how-you-can-refactor-conditional-logic/